# how to pop navigation controller to root in COCOS2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have a FirstViewController that i have attach Cocos2d on it,
when i try to pop thisview back to the rootviewcontroller how can i do it?

i try to send message from CCLayer to FirstViewController to pop to root but not work

here is the code in Firstviewcontroller

- (void)poptoRootview {
  NSLog(@"poptoRootview");
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think cocos2d supports the UIKIT navigationController but i could be wrong.. I think you have to keep track of which Scene you are on manually.